# How to compare file names in SharePoint Library to check if they are unique or not using PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

I have few folders and sub-folders in SharePoint document library. I need to compare if the file names in all folders and sub-folders are unique or not.

Is there any PowerShell script which will help me?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to query the library using caml query, and specifically use

```
<FieldRef Name='FsObjType'/><Value Type='Text'>0</Value>
```

in the query set the ViewAttributes of the query object to 'RecursiveAll'.

Then you can use the item collection to check for duplicates. And this can be done using powershell just Google it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution below is not optimal but easy to use:

1. Download and install the [SPOMOD](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/SharePoint-Module-for-5ecbbcf0)
2. Run [Connect-SPOCSOM](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32334.sharepoint-online-spomod-cmdlets-resources.aspx)
3. Run:

   ```
   $files=(Get-SPOListItems alib -IncludeAllProperties $true -Recursive)
   foreach($file in $files){ foreach ($file2 in $files){ if ($file.FileLeafRef -eq $file2.FileLeafRef -and $file.ID -ne $file2.ID) {$file.FileRef}}}
   ```

[image]

`alib` is the name of your library